# Cassandra ccm not installed as application on windows 10

Tags: cassandra, ccm

I have installed cassandra ccm tool on my windows 10 machine, and it got installed in directory 'C:\Python27\Scripts':

[image]

I have also added path to env variable PATH, but running ccm commands is not working:

> ccm create -h

> 'ccm' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

Is installation of ccm wrong?I see it's not installed as application.

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned here in this blog https://www.datastax.com/blog/ccm-20-and-windows. Most probably path is not updated correctly.

Comment: Can you update in answer what was missing so other users who face same issue can find solution to their problems?

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked on https://community.datastax.com/questions/11860/ so I'm reposting my answer here.

The most common causes of the reported error above are:

- `PYTHON_HOME` is not set
- `PYTHON_HOME` is not included in the `PATH` environment variable

As a side note, there are too many prerequisites for `ccm` to run on Windows so I recommend running Cassandra on Docker or better yet, use [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add .PY to PATHEXT system variable.